# NSData writeToFile:atomically: doesn't immediately save the file

Tags: ios, nsdata

I'm downloading an SQLite db from the web into my iPad app. If I write it to disk setting `atomically: YES` I can't immediately use it because even though the file is there, sqlite complains that the tables aren't there. If I use `atomically = NO` or I delay the opening of the file a few instants then I don't have this problem.

I guess I could go about it by setting `atomically = NO` but then again **is there some sort of guarantee that the *whole* file has been written to disk right after the writeToFile: call?** So far my db is not that big but it will eventually, plus I don't know how long to wait for in other devices.

Apple docs say that this method returns `YES` if the operation succeedes but obviously that does not take into account the "lag" saving the file.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

EDIT: I see other people are having [the same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11134483/nsdata-writetofile-not-completely-written-when-reading).

Comment: I found this stack overflow thread that describes atomic file writing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2705076/difference-between-writing-to-file-atomically-and-not

What I'm guessing is, you're trying to access the file before the OS writes it to the permanent store. Is there a reason you absolutely have to write atomically?

Comment: That was my guess too and I'm trying to figure out a way around it. The reason I have to write atomically is that if for some reason the thing crashes my main db will get corrupted, rendering my app unusable.

Comment: How are you actualy downloading and writing?

Comment: Downloading with AFNetworking and when this is done, a callback block is executed. Inside this block I use NSData to write the db to disk. The download works fine though, only the writing is problematic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the link, the operation will either write completely or fail.

With that in mind, write atomically on another thread, and then do something like this!

```
while (![[FileManager defaultFileManager] fileExistsAtPath:yourEventualDBPath]) {

[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:.5];

}
```

Comment: Nick, them problem is that the file EXISTS but the contents are not fully written to it by the time the method returns YES so this solution won't work (but thanks for the idea anyways!)

Comment: Can you put a blocking call in place while the file is writing? You can also use a while loop and check the hash of the file being written versus the downloaded file?

Comment: How do you do a blocking call? The hash will probably work but I think it is overkill for such a common task as this (and on some downloads I don't control what's sent to me so I can't include the hash). I'm surprised no one hasn't reported anything like this.

Comment: You can do a blocking call by using the `waitUntilFinished:YES` parameter on a `performSelector` call.