# Guarantees on when iOS will write to files in Documents directory?

Tags: ios, file, file-io

I can't seem to come up with an answer for this.  Are the 'guarantees' of when iOS will perform file synchronization specified?

*Given the following scenario:*

1. The app writes a csv file to the app's Documents directory on the device and closes the file handle.
2. The the user quickly 'backgrounds' the app.

Are we able to safely assume that the pending writes to the file will get posted?

What about if #2 was a crash?

Comment: This might answer your question:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/2705102/906830

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When writing to file, if you use the `Atomically` option and the app crashes in the middle of the write, no file is created.

If you don't use that option and a crash occurs, you will have a corrupt file.

[drawnonward's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2705102/906830)

Comment: Great.  I totally missed atomically: